# Django (v4) request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] not working anymore?

Tags: python, django

I had been using for years (Django 1.9 & Python 2.7) `request.META` dictionary and `['REMOTE_ADDR']` header to get client's IP address.
I have recently moved to Django 4.1.5 and found out that my code is not able anymore to get client's IP address, so I had to use:

```
x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
if x_forwarded_for:
    ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
else:
    ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
return ip
```

which works fine.

I've tested my old code in development mode and tried to log `request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')`. The code will log IP only if the IP address is localhost (127.0.0.1). With any other IP address, `REMOTE_ADDR` header stays blank.

I'm just curious, could someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Do you use intermediate proxies like nginx or something like that ? Maybe request headers manipulated before receive to Django level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your intermediate proxies like nginx, apache, etc if you use one in between of your requests and web application. sometimes proxies manipulate request headers before sending it to web application

for instance for Nginx you could use something like this ([source](https://serverfault.com/questions/377210/nginx-clear-x-forwarded-for-before-setting)):

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that nginx would change the behavior of getting the value from META dictionary (I've been using Apache previously and it worked).